# Decoding HTML content based upon language

Tags: c#, html, decode

When I download HTML, I first look at the response headers to determine what encoding is used. Sometimes the Content-Type header does not specify the encoding. Even if I retrieve the encoding from the meta tag such as:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

it is still possible that the content contains characters that are not decoding properly. For instance, the iso-8859-1 is typically used to encode German characters. However in the HTML, there is content such as this:

```
&Ouml;ffnungszeiten
```

where &Ouml is encoded for the German character Ö. Even if I open the stream using the iso-8859-1 encoding, &Ouml remains encoded as-is. How do I decode the HTML so that the correct characters appear. There is another meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="language" content="de" />
```

and the browser probably is using this to decode the characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the encoding is actually called "HTML encoding" and is not specific to a language but rather to HTML itself. Using:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode
```

will convert any non-readable characters.